# How to run CMake unit tests with MSBuild.exe

Tags: msbuild, cmake

Upon generating a Vistual Studio project from a CMake build file, CMake generates a solution with a sub-project called RUN_TESTS.vcproj that runs all unit tests as a post build action.

How can you invoke the RUN_TESTS from the command prompt using msbuild.exe?

Running `msbuild RUN_TESTS.vcproj` from the build directory does not work.

Under UNIX you would do a simple `make test` for Makefiles generated by CMake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be no way to run the tests through MSBuild.exe. You can invoke the tests with the executable ctest.exe which is part of the CMake installation:

```
ctest -C "Debug"
```

This will run the tests associated with the project's "Debug" configuration.

Comment: @GermánDiago If you've built for release instead of debug, try ```ctest -C "Release"```

Comment: as the other answers explain, this can also be run with msbuild

Answer (score 4):

You need open an "Administrator: Visual Studio Command Pormpt" that you can find under the Visual Studio tool. Then, running "msbuild RUN_TESTS.vcproj" should work.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use CMake to build:

```
cd <path_to_build_dir>
cmake.exe --build . --target RUN_TESTS --config release
```

The `--build` functionality of CMake wraps around the build-system you're using, so in your case it would use MsBuild, on Linux it would use g++ or similar. It's a good solution if you want to provide portable build-scripts for your project.

Admittedly you would rather use the above for building the INSTALL target. CTest is the tool of choice in your case.

Comment: Other possible syntax:
`cmake.exe --build . --config release --target test`